# How to apply code, userform and button to many other files?

Tags: vba, excel

Fairly new to VBA. I've written a code which does a variety of things and I'm fairly happy with where it's at.

It's triggered through a button in an excel sheet which calls a subfunction.

The issue I'm having is that the excel sheet I've written the code for is a sheet which we use at work often and save copies of. It's a quote form and we have ~5,000+ copies of different quotes, all in one folder.

Since I've only written the code in one of the copies, is there a way to create a program or something which copies the button and code/userform from the "Source" workbook, to all the others in a specified folder?

I'd like to have the button in the same location so it's consistent.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: It might be easier to host the code in one workbook and then use Application.OnDoubleClick to use the code on a sheet you double click on (rather than duplicating the code hundreds of times)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively this code will import a code module saved as a .bas file into all the spreadsheets in a folder

```
 Sub Demo()

    Dim s As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    s = Dir("\\yourfolderpath\yourdoldername\*.xlsm")
    Do While s <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("\\yourfolderpath\yourdoldername\" & s)

        Dim VBComps As VBIDE.VBComponents
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent

        Set VBComps = wb.VBProject.VBComponents
        For Each VBComp In VBComps
            If VBComp.Name = "Your module name" Then
                VBComps.Remove VBComp
                Exit For
            End If
        Next VBComp

        VBComps.Import "C:\your dir\your module name.bas"
        wb.Close True
        s = Dir()
    Loop


 End Sub
```

But - you must have "Trust access to the VBA project model" ticked in your security centre, and have set a reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility " in Tools,references in the vb editor

Comment: Does this mean I'll have to go into every file and ensure these are set?

That would be fairly time intensive, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: No - it's a general setting for excel. As long as it's set before running the routine you should be ok. You'll need to add code to draw the button and attach it to your routine, but that's googleable